# Issues getting the secondary drop down to validate when using onchange

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to get the selected drop down printerType to alert user when the printer type value is not selected but only when the user selects request the printertype box shows up. The issue I have is that it doesn't alert the user that it is not filled. The others work fine. I hope this is understanding may be little confusing.    the JavaScript code is at the bottom.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Systems Request</title>
    <!--bootstrap-->
      <link href="Assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
              <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="../Assets/javascript/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="../Assets/javascript/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
            <!--custom css-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="Assets/css/style.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="Assets/css/responsive.css">
            <script src="Assets/Javascript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type=
            "text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
            <script src="Assets/javascript/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="Assets/Javascript/textboxname_autocomplete.js" type=
            "text/javascript"></script>

            <style type="text/css">

    .dropdown{
      width: 292px;
      height: 45px;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      background-color: pink;
    }
            </style>
    </head>


    <body style="background-image: url('../Systems/Assets/images/background.jpg')">
     <?php include("includes/createHeader.php");?>
      <section id="container">

        <h2>Systems Request</h2>
        <form name="systems" id="systems-form" action="Pages/InsertProcess.php" method="post"onsubmit="return formCheck(this);">
        <div id="wrapping" class="clearfix">
          <section id="aligned">
          <label class="label">LanID</label><br><br>
          <input type="text" name="lanId" id="lanId"  autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" class="txtinput" >

          <label class="label">Employee Name</label><br><br>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name"   autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" class="txtinput">

            <!--manager access db list info located in the includes folder-->
            <label class="label">Manager</label><br><br>
            <?php include("includes/accessDB_ManagerData.php");?>

           <!--department dropdownlist located in the includes folder-->
           <label class="label">Department</label><br><br>
            <?php include("includes/departmentDropdownList.php");?>

            <!--Request Issue list info located in the includes folder-->
            <label class="label">Request Issue</label><br><br>

    <!-- #start of Request Issues-->

    *<select name ="request" id="request" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex==3){this.form['printerType'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['printerType'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
    <option value =""><?php echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Select Request Issue...'?></option>
    <option value ="RESET CASE"><?php echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reset Case'?></option>
    <option value ="RESET WM PASSWORD"><?php echo "&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RESET WM PASSWORD"?></option>
    <option value ="REPLACE TONER"><?php echo "&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;REPLACE TONER"?></option>
    <option value ="FIX PRINTER"><?php echo "&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FIX PRINTER"?></option>
    <option value ="FIX DEVICES"><?php echo "&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FIX DEVICE"?></option>
    <option value ="SAFETY HIGH REQUEST"><?php echo "&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SAFETY HIGH REQUEST"?></option>
    <option value ="OTHER"><?php echo "&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;OTHER"?></option>
    </select><br>
    <!-- #end of Request Issues-->*

    ***<select class="dropdown" style="visibility:hidden;"  name="printerType" id="printerType" >
    <option Value="">Please select Printer Type</option>
    <option Value="FS 4200DN">Kyocera FS4200DN</option>
    <option Value="FS 3040MFP">Kyocera FS3040MFP</option>
    <option Value="Kyocera ">Kyocera FS1370DN </option>
    <option Value="OKI MPS710C">OKI MPS710C</option>
    <option Value="OKI MPS711C">OKI MPS711C</option>
    <option Value="Sharp MX450N">Sharp MX450N</option>
    </select>***
    <br/>
        <label class="label">Request Description </label><br><br>
          <textarea name="request_comments" id="message" placeholder="Enter Description of Issue" tabindex="5" class="txtblock"></textarea>


          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn" tabindex="7" value="Submit">
          <br style="clear:both;">
            <?php #Hidden inputs for Status, tech comments, tech completed, tech completed date?>
                    <input name="status" type="hidden" value="RECEIVED">
                    <input name="comments" type="hidden" value="No Comment ">
                    <input name="compUser" type="hidden" value="Unassigned">
                    <input name="compDt" type="hidden" value="Not Completed">

          </section>
          </section>
        </div> 
        </form>
      </section>
     <?php include("includes/footer.php");?>
     <script src="Assets/Javascript/gen_validatorv4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    var frmvalidator = new Validator("systems");

    if (document.getElementById('request').selectedIndex==3){
     frmvalidator.addValidation("printerType","req","Please enter Printer Type");
    }

    else{

    frmvalidator.addValidation("lanId","req","Please enter LanID");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("request_comments","req","Please enter request comments");
    }
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change a few things like getElementbByName to getElementById. also added a function called updateValidation to add to the onchange part of the selected box and added `frmvalidator.clearAllValidations();`to the function along with added the two other textboxes lanId and request_comments to the if statement.

```
<select name ="request" id="request" onchange=" if (this.selectedIndex==3){this.form.printerType.style.visibility='visible'} else {this.form.printerType.style.visibility='hidden'};updateValidation()">


<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateValidation (){
      frmvalidator.clearAllValidations();

    if (document.getElementById('request').selectedIndex==3){

    frmvalidator.addValidation("lanId","req","Please enter LanID");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("printerType","req","Please enter Printer Type");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("request_comments","req","Please enter request comments");

    }

    else{

    frmvalidator.addValidation("lanId","req","Please enter LanID");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("request_comments","req","Please enter request comments");
    }
    }
     </script>
```